# Search configuration, exclude word/phrase from index

Tags: search, tags, search-configuration

I know I can exclude things down to a column level, but it is possible to exclude a certain word and or phrase from the search indexing?

I have a tag called "Not Applicable" and the client wishes to not have this phrase displayed in the search results, it is just the phrase, they want to see the result without this tag being shown.

Is this possible via configuration instead of having to create a custom results page?

**[update]**
Been playing with the noisexxx.txt files, but due to the way noise/stop words keep phrases, they still appear, I am going to try with the xslt transformation as suggested here next.

Comment: Can you exclude Tags/phrases through the Scoping rules?  This is a little more atomic than anything I have tried so I don't know if it's feasible but maybe with the Search results xslt you can exclude this from showing up in the results?

Comment: I'm trying but all I seem to be able to do it exclude a whole result, not just filter this tag from showing in the results. It's a very fine tuning requirement, I thought maybe break words as they have this but I can't get it working.

Comment: I thought the Refinement Panel in the results page only affected what it showed for associated tags if you changed the Data View properties, but I will admit its been awhile since I have been on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the search results but don't want the phrase to show up in the results page, you could fool around with the search results xsl to either strip out the phrase or at least not highlight it.

Comment: This might be the only solution, I will keep playing, this is what I wanted to stay away from, filtering results like this in xslt is a bit heavy imo.

Comment: Yes, I think it is an interesting requirement that users need to be able to search for the phrase and get results but not see the search phrase in the results.  I have customized our search results xslt and once you get in there, it isn't so bad. XSLT work is not one of my favorite tasks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add the words 'Not Applicable' to the list of noise words in `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Data\Config\noiseenu.txt"`, but that of cause means that you won't be able to search for either of them.

The change of noise words should be followed by:

- stop/start osearch14
- Full crawl

Comment: This was my issue in that it is a phrase, however I think not is already there since it is a keyword, I can take a look and have a play.